# Identifying a kids movie with a villain named Cobra and they use pineapples for something

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I hit a random Roku channel on my tv and a movie in spanish showed up where kids are the protagonists. There is an asian villain (bald and dressed like a monk) who I think is named Cobra. The villain also has long black nails on his index and thumb.

They are fighting for a blue stone and a medallion possibly.  The kids know martial arts and the main kid is a caucasion kid with brown hair.

The villain scratches himself with his nail (which may be poisoned) and falls into a vortex of some sort.

The main character is named Billy if I heard it right.

More info:

- The movie is most likely in English and I just saw a Spanish dub.
- The kids dig up some medallion due to a time travel thing and place a blue stone in it.  This is used to take them home.
- Pineapples are used somehow to help them escape a prison, I don't know how.
- The story is narrated,as a guy is telling a story to his kids.

Comment: jman - as I remember, military slang for a hand grenade is "pineapple", so if the charactersw were really throwing exploding pineapples instead of hand grenades, its obvious where the writer got the idea of exploding pineapples from..

Comment: I had to look it up, but Cobra Commander never used exploding pineapples in a nefarious plot to make a volcano erupt - which was my first thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the 2013 film ['The Lost Medallion: The Adventures of Billy Stone'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Medallion:_The_Adventures_of_Billy_Stone).

The review on wikipedia mentions a medallion, a time-travel theme, a main protagonist called Billy (obvs) and a villain named Cobra. A quick glance at the video below shows a scene where the kids throw explosive pineapples at the villain.

> *The goons discover them and chase them through the city. After a bit,
>   the kids, thinking they have lost the men, head back to Billy's home,
>   only to find that the goons have arrived before them and tied up
>   Billy's dad. **Billy yells "I wish this whole mess had never happened!"
>   and the medallion sends both Billy and Allie back in time (200 years).***
>
> ...
>
> *The wise man tells them that they must complete tasks, and in return
>   he will teach them how to defeat Cobra, the enemy that attacked the
>   camp, and the evil warlord who keeps the natives in terror, and get
>   the medallion back. **The kids travel to the island of Cobra.** On the
>   beach of Cobra's island, Faleaka is shot by an arrow and killed.*

Comment: That would be my guess as well. As I recall the pineapples exploded (I was perhaps nine at the time... so it's been a while though.)

Comment: Yes this is it exactly thanks, markes as answered!

Comment: Where's GI Joe when you need him?